# Ruby: how to Last day of last month

Tags: ruby

Please help me with the code i.e how to get Last day of Last month.

i.e. if today date is 06-11-2016 (dd-mm-yyyy) => output: 31-10-2016

Comment: I could not solve my issue with the question already asked in community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
require 'date'

t = Date.today
Date.new(t.year, t.month) - 1
 => #<Date: 2016-10-31 ((2457693j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: what about `t - t.day` ?) It should return the same result, but without creating new instance of `Date`)

Comment: It works, cool :)

Comment: Hello Alex and Ursus, I have tried to get a weekday from a given date. and the below code worked for me. Just want to know, Is there a better way to do this `require 'date'

d = Date.today
weekday = Date.parse( '#{d.day} #{d.month} #{d.year}' ) 
puts weekday.strftime('%A')

Output: **Monday** `

Comment: Well, it's a matter of tastes. You could do just `Date.today.strftime('%A')`

Comment: Thank you very much